# std::vector constructor with two input arguments

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, std

I came across a piece of C++ code in one of my projects that initializes a vector with two inputs.

One of the inputs is an existing array, and the other is the same array plus the array length.

I found a similar piece of code on another site:

```
// Create an array of string objects
std::string arr[] = {"first", "sec", "third", "fourth"};

// Initialize vector with a string array
std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string));

for(std::string str : vecOfStr)
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Can someone explain what `arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)` is?

The website that this code was referenced in said that this was the corresponding constructor used:

```
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Comment: *I found a similar piece of code on another site:* -- And when you're done with that code, change that line to `std::array<std::string, 4> arr = {"first", "sec", "third", "fourth"};` so that the number of elements is simply `arr.size()`, and not the often misused "sizeof" trick (that doesn't work if `arr` is passed to a function as a pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` itself is of type `std::string[4]`. When passed to a function, it is [decayed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) to pointer to the first element. In the expression `arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)`, the first occurrence of `arr` is again decayed. The second is not. `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)` therefore evaluates to `4` which is the array extent. The whole expression `arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)` then evaluates to a pointer to the position past the final element in `arr`. This is usually called the off-the-end iterator. This effectively invokes the constructor `vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, ...)` where `InputIterator` is instantiated with `std::string*`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most important thing here you need to understand what's happening is that `std::string[]` can be implicitly converted to `std::string*` (a pointer to the first element in the array).

So `arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)` in your example is a pointer to one past the end of the array (`sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string)` gives the number of elements in the array).

So the two elements being passed to `vector`'s constructor are pointers, which can act as iterators, and initialise the `vector` with the four elements from `arr`.